# Gradual opacity decrement using Action in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions

I am trying to create an action in photoshop which duplicate the selected layer and decrease its opacity 0.5 less than the selected layer.

I tried to record action but its always sets fixed opacity which was at the time of recording action.

Do anyone have idea on achieving above thing, please help me.

Comment: Javascript could also work here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve that using Actions, your best bet is creating a Script for that. You can use purely Script for this, but if you still want to incorporate Actions into it (as the trigger), you can set the Action to use a Script after duplicating the current layer.

Open up a text editor, give it any name you want (the Script's name is the same as the filename), and paste this in:

```
#target photoshop

app.activeDocument.activeLayer.opacity = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.opacity / 2;
```

Save it as a `.js` or `.jsx` in your Scripts' folder (`X:\~\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop XX\Presets\Scripts`), and you can select `Insert Menu Item` from the Action menu to insert the script *after* the duplicate action.

[image: Should look something like this.]

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you want a half of the previous opacity:**

Go to the new layer and wipe the whole area once with a big solid eraser that has opacity=50%

The drawbacks:

- permanet change, the opacity slider cannot take it back
- works only for bitmap image layers

Other possiblities:

- add a 50% grey layer mask, apply it as you remove the mask or
- have originally a solid white layer mask, reduce the brightness of the mask 50% in the new layer

The last one is the most undestructive method and it applies also with adjustment layers